# Can't boot 16.04.1 from USB on Windows 10 HP laptop

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, hp, windows-10

I have an HP 15-u011dx (HP Envy) laptop with Windows 10 on it. I recently became interested in Ubuntu and decided to get a PNY 64GB USB 3.0 flash drive so I can boot Ubuntu from there instead of installing it on the laptop. I downloaded 16.04.1 (amd64) and used Rufus to create a bootable USB drive of that version using the tutorial on the site. However, my laptop always boots to Windows 10, even after changing the BIOS settings to the following:

[BIOS boot settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1y1a.jpg)

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: I would first try to prove that the USB stick is actually booting in efi mode on another computer.

Comment: ^Just tried it on my Dad's Windows 7 Lenovo laptop. It worked, but I had to hit F12 at startup to go to boot config and select the flash drive to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured it out: I was trying to run it from the USB 3.0 port when it wasn't booting up, so I tried it on the 2.0 port and it worked fine. And I noticed a setting in the BIOS called "USB3.0 Configuration in Pre-OS," which I changed from "Enabled" to "Auto." Thanks to this, I can now boot from the USB 3.0 port!

I think I'll keep the other boot settings. Thanks anyway, guys!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you make sure when setting up the device in rufus under "Partition scheme and target system type" it is set to MBR parition scheme for bios or uefi. Try writing to the stick with that set then try booting let me know your results and I will provide more help if needed.

Comment: Actually, I appear to have solved the problem by running it off a USB 2.0 port instead of 3.0. Is there any way to run it from 3.0? I'll try changing the USB 3.0 config to Auto. And is there any difference between booting from UEFI and non-UEFI?

Comment: Yes there is. If you install in UEFI mode most modern devices use UEFI and secureboot which will require you to disable secure boot to install third party drivers like WIFI and plugins like flash.. if you have an option in your UEFI/BIOS menu to disable secure boot I honestly suggest just getting that out of the way.

Comment: From there its just a matter of the method that is used by the kernel to interface with your BIOS/UEFI/firmware all in all comparability in my experience with UEFI and linux is quite troublesome mostly because of the people who develop the laptops...In recent years linus has actually made a great deal of change kernel wise to fix most of these issues so all in all its really upto you on installing in UEFI if it WORKS. As for secureboot in my opinion its not needed and gets in the way of third party app/driver support.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to self diagnose and figure out a solution good job. Also, welcome to the linux community!